# I'm trying to setup Moodle 2.3 (not 2.5) ver with nginx latest build

Tags: php, nginx

I tried to use the rewrite rule from the link above:

rewrite ^(.*.php)(/)(.*)$ $1?file=/$3 last;
which is not working in 2.3-2.5 ver. I assume it worked in 1.9. Now Moodle is using different path:

http://example.com/moodle/pluginfile.php/26/mod_scorm/content/1/index.html

Some of nginx rules:

location ^~ /moodle {
     location ~*    ^.+.(?:css|js|htc|xml|jpe?g|gif|png|ico|bmp|svg|swf|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|tiff?|txt|rtf|cgi|bat|pl|dll|aspx?|class|otf|ttf|woff|eot|less)$ {
         add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
         access_log off;
         expires 30d;
         tcp_nodelay off;
         try_files $uri =404;
     }
     location ~* ^/moodle/.*.php$ {
         include      includes/fastcgi_params.conf;
         try_files $uri @dynamic;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
         fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
         fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;
         fastcgi_keep_conn on;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;

```
 }
 rewrite (^.*\.php)(/.*) $1 last;
```

}

Comment: $document_root$fastcgi_path_info; fastcgi_read_timeout 1200; fastcgi_keep_conn on; fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;